# conda does not exist in the anaconda/bin directory

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

As described in the title - the anaconda/bin directory does not contain `conda`: it *does* have `conda-server` as well as 148 other binaries.

The only place `conda` exists is

```
 ~/anaconda/pkgs/conda-4.2.9-py35_0/bin/conda
```

- Why would this be the case?
- Is it safe to add that `pkgs/..` dir to the `$PATH`?

Comment: If someone came here looking for `bin/conda` - be aware that it is  `scripts/conda` now

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was a simple reinstall.